# Pygame Install Problems

Tags: python, pygame, pycharm, installation

When I say problems, I mean 200% in over my head, in need of some serious hand-holding...

Tried to install Pygame and seems to work in the Command Prompt, the example 'aliens' game runs, when I enter the command

'py -m pygame.examples.aliens'

But when I open PyCharm and try to import, it says no pygame module exists...
Can someone please shed some light on this? I can tell you that I installed the pygame program to the desktop and all it put was 2 folders, one named 'Lib', the other named 'Include'...

Inside this Lib file is the site-packages file, which contains all the stuff you'd see in the External Libraries window in PyCharm, in fact I have ALL of those files and directories accessible in PyCharm, however, the whole site-packages file is red for some reason, and, like I said, trying to import does nothing.

Please Help!

Answer (score 1):

Go to Pycharm File -> Project Settings -> find Project Interpreter

In the topright you'll find a plus sign. Click that, search for pygame in the list, install it from there.

You should now have a properly installed pygame usable in PyCharm.

You may want to clean up your Desktop, too.